# integration of an open curve about isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I know if I integrate a circular arc of an angle $\theta < 2\pi$ about an isolated singularity of the complex funciton I would get a fraction $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$ of the residue of that singularity. For example, integrrating $\frac{1}{z}$ about an arc of radius 1 about $z=0$ would give $i\pi$.

But I am not sure how this applies to situation where we integrate along an open curve (that is not an arc) near some isolated singularity. Say, we want to integrate $\frac{1}{z}$ along $x=1, -i<y<i$. That gave me $\frac{i\pi}{2}$ which I can see since I could deform this segment to an arc of angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This I am still ok with.

1. What about integrating $\frac{1}{z}$ along $x=1, 0<y<2i$? I cannot tell to which arc this would deform.
2. The case when we have more than 1 isolated singularities, say, $\frac{1}{(z)(z-(1+i))}$ along $x=2, 0<y<3i$?

These are just some random examples so I would prefer if answers are as general as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(z)=1/z$, restricted to a simply connected domain which does not contain $0$, has a primitive function, $F(z)=\log(z)$. Thus, if $\gamma$ is a curve that goes from $1$ to $1+2i$ without going around $0$, we have$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z}=\log(1+2i)-log(1).$$

The function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-z_1)\ldots(z-z_n)}$$can be expressed as a sum$$f(z)=\frac{a_1}{z-z_1}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{z-z_n}.$$Then its integral along a curve is equal to the sum of integrals which can be calculated as above.

Comment: @Yuval I realised I need to let the radius of the arc (in my first paragraph) tends to zero to get the residue theorem in effect so that it would give $i\pi$. Does this mean as long as we are intergrating along an open curve that is at a non-zero distance to a singularity we dont use the residue theorem, and so that singularities do not contribute at all?

Comment: @MartinCheung Note that when considering open curves, the integral of an entire function does not necessarily vanish either. Hence, residues cannot give all the needed information for integrating.